# Speed optimization using Piscina

Tags: javascript, csv

I want to analyze a lot of urls in short period.
For analyze the urls, I am using Wappalyzer module.
Piscina is what I chose for speed optimization and it is working well.
However, I am not satisfied with the current speed and I need faster one.

Here is my current code.

index.js

> ```
> const Piscina = require("piscina");
> const { program } = require("commander");
>
> const { readCsv, cleanFile } = require("./src/csv");
> const { resolve, join } = require("path");
> const { chunks } = require("./src/utils");
>
> async function run({
>   chunksNum = 500,
>   enableLogging = true,
>   inputFile,
>   outputFile,
>   enableConfidence = false,
>   limitTab = 5,
> }) {
>   console.time("Analyze time");
>
>   const inputFileLocation = join(__dirname, inputFile);
>   const outputFileLocation = join(__dirname, outputFile);
>
>   console.log("Reading input csv file...");
>   let urls = await readCsv(inputFileLocation);
>   // urls = urls.slice(0, 1)
>   console.log(`* Done!, total urls will be analyzed: ${urls.length}`);
>
>   try {
>     const urlChunks = chunks(urls, chunksNum);
>     console.log(`* Total threads: ${urlChunks.length}`);
>
>     const pool = new Piscina({
>       filename: resolve(__dirname, "./src/worker-pool.js"),
>     });
>     console.log("Start analyzing...");
>
>     await cleanFile(outputFileLocation);
>     await Promise.all(
>       urlChunks.map((urls, index) => {
>         console.log(`-- Thread ${index} will analyze ${urls.length} urls`);
>         return pool.run({
>           urls,
>           enableLogging,
>           limitTab,
>           threadIndex: index,
>           outputFile: outputFileLocation,
>         });
>       })
>     );
>
>     console.log("Writing results to csv...");
>     // await writeCsv(outputFileLocation, results.flat(), enableConfidence)
>     console.log("Writing results done!");
>   } catch (error) {
>     console.error(error);
>   }
>   console.timeEnd("Analyze time");
> }
>
> program
>   .option("-c, --chunks <number>", "Split urls into n chunks (default 1000)")
>   .option(
>     "-lm, --limitTab <number>",
>     "Limit chrome tabs per chrome instance (default 10)"
>   )
>   .option("-l, --log", "Enable logging (default false)")
>   .option("-i, --input <file>", "Input file (default urls.csv)")
>   .option("-o, --output <file>", "Input file (default result.csv)")
>   .option(
>     "-cfd, --confidence",
>     "Write confidence results to csv (default false)"
>   );
>
> program.parse(process.argv);
>
> const options = program.opts();
> const chunksNum = parseInt(options.chunks) || 1000;
> const enableLogging = options.log || false;
> const enableConfidence = options.confidence || false;
> const limitTab = parseInt(options.limitTab) || 10;
>
> const inputFile = options.input || "urls.csv";
> const outputFile = options.output || "result.csv";
>
> run({
>   chunksNum,
>   enableLogging,
>   inputFile,
>   outputFile,
>   enableConfidence,
>   limitTab,
> });
> ```

package.json

> ```
> {
>   "name": "wappalyzer",
>   "version": "1.0.0",
>   "description": "",
>   "main": "index.js",
>   "scripts": {
>     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
>   },
>   "keywords": [],
>   "author": "",
>   "license": "ISC",
>   "dependencies": {
>     "commander": "^9.2.0",
>     "csv": "^6.0.5",
>     "piscina": "^3.2.0",
>     "wappalyzer": "^6.10.23"
>   }
> }
> ```

urls.csv

> ```
> akwam.io
> bciseguros.cl
> ctctusercontent.com
> haodeplus.com
> aicaimei.com
> papik.pro
> prixdubaril.com
> cambiumast.com
> fyeds2.com
> jimcontent.com
> dbankcloud.com
> sura.cl
> tazkarti.com
> coke.com
> secureholiday.net
> petycjeonline.com
> aso1.net
> ookla.com
> samsungpromotions.claims
> shec.edu.cn
> tui.ch
> filmstreaming.al
> bttba.com
> guizumeimei.com
> xiti.com
> wakefern.com
> housingauthority.gov.hk
> quantserve.com
> jabama.com
> lord-film-cc.me
> xiepp.cc
> yourcovidrecovery.nhs.uk
> leyuman.com
> jse.edu.cn
> kkkkwu.com
> pingit.im
> service-voyages.com
> fiaformula2.com
> junaeb.cl
> yt.be
> windowssearch-exp.com
> tickets.com
> manga1002.com
> yuedyue.com
> nakadashi.pw
> tapmad.com
> mywelfare.ie
> freemangaraw.com
> shukriya90.com
> regudri.xyz
> pgmall.my
> secsso.net
> uab.cat
> job-terminal.com
> swimsuitsforall.com
> sberbank.com
> vic.gov.au
> hondadealers.com
> mptgate.com
> hgq26.com
> lenzmx.com
> minna-no-ginko.com
> vchecks.io
> feed-xml.com
> optoutsub.net
> mengyuanshucheng.com
> utiitsl.com
> beneficiosestudiantiles.cl
> adpool.bet
> csdiran.ir
> aftrk3.com
> 100fanwo.com
> bancolombia.com
> binaamanhaji.com
> tokyo-brain.clinic
> tcloudbaseapp.com
> qimiaomh.com
> 12cm.com.tw
> amplifyapp.com
> 86zw.co
> infinitummovil.net
> sejam.ir
> maeva.com
> ghiseul.ro
> sf024.com
> capcut.net
> fusetracking.com
> mof.gov.cn
> northgate-nes.co.uk
> btbtt20.com
> srvpcn.com
> downxia.com
> googleweblight.com
> ajuda.globo
> likecs.com
> ... more than 8970
> ```

src/analyse.js

> ```
> async function analyzeUrl(wappalyzerInstance, url, enableLogging = false) {
>   // check if the url string has a protocol, if not, add http://
>   if (!url.startsWith('http')) {
>     url = `http://${url}`
>   }
>   if (enableLogging) {
>     console.log('------ Start analyzing: ', url)
>   }
>   const site = await wappalyzerInstance.open(url)
>
>   const results = await site.analyze()
>   const detectResult = await detectSpotifyOrStripeInTechnologies(results.technologies)
>   if (enableLogging) {
>     console.log(`------ Finish analyzing: ${url}; Result: ${detectResult.exist ? `Found ${detectResult.label}!` : 'Not found.'}`)
>   }
> ```

src/csv.js

> ```
> const fs = require('fs')
> const { parse, stringify } = require('csv')
>
> async function readCsv(csvFile) {
>   const urls = []
>   // read the csv file
>   const parser = parse({ columns: false })
>   const stream = fs.createReadStream(csvFile).pipe(parser)
>
>   stream.on('data', (row) => {
>     urls.push(row[0])
>   })
>   // wait for the stream to end and return the urls
>   await new Promise((resolve) => {
>     stream.on('end', () => {
>       resolve(urls)
>     })
>   })
>   return urls
> }
>
>
> //RETURN CSV
> function generateOutputData(data, enableConfidence) {
>   const outputData = data.map(row => {
>     if (row.technologies) {
>       return { url: row.url.slice(7), detect: row.technologies, confidence: row.confidence }
>     }
>     return { url: row.url, detect: row.label || '-' }
>   })
>   return outputData
> }
>
> async function cleanFile(outputFile) {
>   await fs.writeFileSync(outputFile, '', 'utf-8')
> }
>
> async function writeCsv(outputFile, data, enableConfidence) {
>   const outputData = generateOutputData(data, enableConfidence)
>
>   stringify(outputData, { header: true },  (err, output) => {
>     if (err) {
>       console.error(err)
>     }
>     fs.writeFile(outputFile, output, (err) => {
>       if (err) {
>         console.error(err)
>       }
>     })
>   })
>
> }
>
> async function appendCsv(outputFile, data, enableConfidence) {
>   const outputData = generateOutputData(data, enableConfidence)
>
>   stringify(outputData, { header: false }, (err, output) => {
>     if (err) {
>       console.error(err)
>     }
>     fs.appendFile(outputFile, output, (err) => {
>       if (err) {
>         console.error(err)
>       }
>     })
>   })
>
> }
>
> module.exports = {
>   readCsv, writeCsv, appendCsv, cleanFile
> }
>
>
>   return {
>     url, ...results
>   }
> }
>
> module.exports = { analyzeUrl }
> ```

src/utils.js

> ```
> function chunks(arr, chunkSize) {
>   if (chunkSize === 0) return arr
>   let results = [];
>   while (arr.length) results.push(arr.splice(0, chunkSize));
>   return results;
> }
>
> module.exports = { chunks };
> ```

src/worker-pool.js

> ```
> const Wappalyzer = require("wappalyzer");
> const { analyzeUrl } = require("./analyze");
> const { chunks } = require("./utils");
> const { appendCsv } = require("./csv");
>
> module.exports = async ({
>   urls,
>   enableLogging,
>   limitTab = 5,
>   threadIndex,
>   outputFile,
> }) => {
>   const options = {
>     debug: false,
>     delay: 5000,
>     maxDepth: 3,
>     maxUrls: 3,
>     maxWait: 10000,
>     recursive: true,
>     userAgent: "Wappalyzer",
>   };
>
>   const urlChunks = chunks(urls, limitTab);
>   const results = [];
>
>   let finishUrl = 0;
>   for (let chunk of urlChunks) {
>     console.log("---- Create new chrome instance");
>     const wappalyzer = new Wappalyzer(options);
>     await wappalyzer.init();
>     console.log(`---- Open ${chunk.length} tabs in thread ${threadIndex}`);
>     const result = await Promise.all(
>       chunk.map((url) => analyzeUrl(wappalyzer, url, enableLogging))
>     );
>     await appendCsv(outputFile, result.flat(), false);
>     finishUrl += chunk.length;
>     const totalUrls = urlChunks.flat().length;
>     console.log(
>       `---- Finish ${finishUrl}/${totalUrls} urls in thread ${threadIndex}`
>     );
>     results.push(result);
>     await wappalyzer.destroy();
>     console.log("---- Destroy chrome instance");
>   }
>   console.log(`-- Finish thread ${threadIndex}`);
>
>   return results.flat();
> };
> ```

Comment: What have you done to determine the actual bottleneck?

Comment: I didn't do that. Could you recommend some?